# How to support both Portrait and Landscape mode - reusable view with XIBs

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, xib, uiinterfaceorientation

I am new to orientation changes using XIBs.

I saw many questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392230/how-to-design-a-uiview-which-will-work-for-both-landscape-and-portrait-modes), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729539/how-to-create-a-uiview-for-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout), but I can't seem to find simple solution here. I don't want to use any 3rd party framework that will do it, but would rather have step by step way of how should I redesign my XIBs and/or how should I create outlets. And what all should go inside XIB view code (the UIView derivative).

The view XIB don't have any outlets so far and I am not sure which outlets I should provide. Here is the structure of XIB:

[image]

Like the above, I would have 2-3 more XIBs from which I load views, all into same view controllers.

Again, I know how UIViewController can respond to orientation change (`preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` and `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`), but do not know how to load respective XIB with proper outlets upon each of such events.
,

Answer (score 2):

This can be a pretty tricky task. You are correct that you add outlets to your views, and rearrange them programmatically in the view controller. That is a pretty daunting task, and takes a lot of time.

I would suggest using the auto layout tools provided in XCode to make this job easier, and help to make transitions look a lot smoother. Please check the links below:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Reloading the entire XIB every time the user changes orientation can be a good option if you are changing the contents of the view whenever the user changes orientation, not just the arrangement. Take a look at Apples documentation on supporting multiple Interface Orientations.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: +1, thanks. the problem is - it is for iOS 5-7. So simply using autolayout will not help I think.

Comment: Thanks Nirav. There are some interesting solutions to that problem in another SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12411980/enabling-auto-layout-in-ios-6-while-remaining-backwards-compatible-with-ios-5